# RPC data passing

Tags: c, protocols, rpc

I am trying to use a struct to send a message back from server. But I met a problem of result_1 = null. My guess is there is nothing passed back but I do not know how to fix it. Here is my code.

```
msg.x
struct message{
      string timeinfo<255>;
      string cpu<255>;
      string memory<255>;
      string proclist<255>;
};

program MSGPROG {
   version MSGVERS {
      message MSGSEND(void) = 1;
               } = 1;
} = 0x20000000;
```

server side

```
        result.timeinfo= asctime(timeinfo);
        printf ("something: %s\n",result.timeinfo);
        return &result;
```

Client side

```
 #endif  /* DEBUG */

        result_1 = msgsend_1((void*)&msgsend_1_arg, clnt);
        //      if (result_1 == (message *) NULL) {                             
        //              clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");                      
        //      }else{                                                          


        printf("Result time: %s\n",&(*result_1).timeinfo);
          //    }      %%
```

I commented the debug checking to see what happen in result, and tried to change the format of result to be &(*(result_1).timeinfo) and a lot of format. None of them works. The print will be either Result time:(null) or something like segmentation fault...

Here is the result of server, I think the data goes into the result.timeinfo.

```
something: Tue Feb 16 19:52:55 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the address of "something".  You need to strcpy the result.

Comment: what... since *result_ is a message... I think (*result_1).timeinfo should be a string...

Comment: It looks like you are trying a Remote Procedure Call function. string is fine. But when you assign "str", it only assigns the address of the "str" in C. In C++ you can use   str1 = "test" and the "=" operator or copy constructor will take care of assigning if there is one defined. Are you using C or C++?

Comment: I see your point... I am using c right now. So, I should strcpy((*result_1).timeinfo,"something")? But this gives me a segmentation fault...

Comment: It is not clear how msgsend_l returns the pointer to message. If the memory is not allocated for the structure varilable then you will get SIGSEGV.   could you please add the full code.

Comment: It is fine when you define the variable. For example char str[] = "test"; is fine. But when you assign it might have undefined behavior later.

Comment: When you assign a temp string address it might have undefined behavior later unless there is a guarantee the address is not reused. It is always recommended to allocate memory.

Comment: The point is I could delete the sentence of strcpy((*result_1).timeinfo, "something"); and it will give me Result time: (null)

Comment: The client calls the server side function msgsend_1_svc() and the server side function returns the date/time in result. But then I don't understand why you are copying "something" on the result returned by the server function.

Comment: Like I said... I just test if the format of string is correct... It is not a matter...

Comment: if you are getting result_1 is NULL then that indicates the rpc call failed. Are you running both programs on same machines. you could try with loopback ip 127.0.0.1 or localhost and check whether it makes any difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103668/discussion-between-jerrold-gao-and-umamahesh-p).

Comment: I have attempted some tests with a rpc sample. but not able to make it work. I think it needs detail debugging on the server side.